# Python - script counts wrong, but why?

Tags: python, loops, scripting

I'm just at the beginning  to learn Python.
As an exercise I wrote this little script:

*Write a program which repeatedly reads numbers until the user enters "done". Once "done" is entered, print out the total, count, and average of the numbers. If the user enters anything other than a number,
detect their mistake using `try` and `except` and print an error message and skip to the next number.*

It does what it should in general, but: When I played with it a little I noticed one strange behavior: As it takes several (int) numbers after the prompt it won't - and shouldn't - take characters. So far so good, but then I tried a float as input. The script won't take it as valid input but would count it and put the truncated number into the total.

Code:

```
total = float(0)  # sum of items
count = int(0)  # number of items
avrg = float(0)   # average of items
input_in = True
while input_in:
    try:
        line = input('Enter a number: ')
        if line == 'done':
            print('total:', str(total),' count:', str(count),' average:', str(avrg))
            break
        print(line)
        for itervar in line:
            total = total + float(itervar)
            count = count+1
            avrg = total / count
    except:
        print('Invalid input')
```

Output:

```
Enter a number: 1.5
1.5
Invalid input
Enter a number: 5
5
Enter a number: 5
5
Enter a number: 5
5
Enter a number: done
total: 16.0  count: 4  average: 4.0
```

What I tried - and didn't work: Assign the variables line and/or itervar as float().
I tried the included Debugger but I'm not able to understand it.
I have no clue how this could work.

Comment: If you are asking the user to input *a number*, which means *one number*, why are you iterating over what is being input? (by the way the two answers given so far are correct)

Comment: @Booboo: After I understood this - I'm asking it myself. The answer is pretty simple: I didn't know better.

Comment: But you learned something useful about strings and iterating over them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your line:

```
for itervar in line:
```

Is walking over each **character** of the input, which for your first input (`1.5`) results in three iterations:

```
1
.
5
```

So for the first iteration, your total is increased by `1`, and for the *second* iteration, you're trying to use `.` as a number, and failing. (Hence why your final value, after adding `5 + 5 + 5`, is `16`)

Instead of using a for loop to iterate over your input, you should look into *converting the entire input string* into a number.

***And as an added bonus...***

Consider whether you actually need to be recalculating your average each loop. Since you have the `total`, and the `count`, I'd recommend instead calculating your average value *on-demand*, as a result of those two numbers.

Comment: Thx for pointing out the mechanism of the `for` loop. As for your _bonus_ - I have to think about this.

Answer (score 2):

As you've already figured out, `input()` returns a string.

When you iterate through a string with a `for` loop, you iterate over each character individually. This means that, when you enter `'1.5'`, you get three iterations:

```
itervar = '1'
itervar = '.'
itervar = '5'
```

Due to how you wrote your code, the first one goes correctly, but then when it tries to convert '.' to a float, it produces an error.

Why not just consider the entire input as a whole, instead of character-by-character?

```
line = input('Enter a number: ')
        if line == 'done':
            print('total:', str(total),' count:', str(count),' average:', str(avrg))
            break
        print(line)
        total = total + float(line)
        count = count+1
        avrg = total / count
```

Comment: As in the OP and in here, you don't need to cast total, count and avrg with str() in `print('total:', str(total),' count:', str(count),' average:', str(avrg))` since you are not concatenating strings.